# Cannot assign a value of type '[Thing]' to a value of type '[Any]'

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, swift

I'm struggling with what seems like a simple Swift problem.

I've declared a `struct` with a static function that returns some instances:

```
struct Thing {
    static func allTheThings() -> [Thing] {
        ...
    }
}
```

I've got a `CustomViewController` with an property declared:

```
var objects = [Any]()
```

In the subclass of that controller in `viewDidLoad()`, I'm trying to assign the `objects` property.

```
objects = Thing.allTheThings()
```

But I'm getting a compiler error

```
Cannot assign a value of type '[Thing]' to a value of type '[Any]'
```

Isn't that the whole point of `Any`?

This works:

```
objects = Thing.allTheThings().map { $0 }
```

But this doesn't

```
let things = Thing.allTheThings().map { $0 }
objects = things
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: `Any` can hold object, not structure, structure doesn't come into categories of objects, or `Any`. `Any` can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Swift can convert Thing to Any but not [Thing] to [Any].

The reason this works

```
 objects = Thing.allTheThings().map { $0 }
```

is that the compiler can infer that the type of $0 is Any, but in the second example

```
let things = Thing.allTheThings().map { $0 }
```

it infers $0 to be of type Thing. You end up with the variable things being of type [Thing], which means that the assignment

```
objects = things
```

will mean a conversion from [Thing] to [Any] which does not work.

Comment: If you make Thing a class instead of a struct, you can use AnyObject instead of Any. Then you should be able to assign a value of type [Thing] to a variable of type [AnyObject]